# How to adjust subfigure caption width?

Tags: subfloats, tex-core, subfig

I'm trying to put subfigures side by side. I used the following code.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\begin{minipage}[b][1\totalheight][t]{0.45\columnwidth}%

\subfigure[subfig a]{\label{fig:sa}}
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{clust3-actual12-outlier-removed}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b][1\totalheight][t]{0.45\columnwidth}%

\subfigure[subfig b]{\label{fig:sb}}
\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{clust11_long-actual75-outlier-removed}
\end{minipage}

\end{centering}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
```

I am getting the following output

[image]

I get error if I try the more usual

```
 \begin{subfigure}
   ...
 \end{subfigure}
```

This may have something to do with the ICML template I'm working on ([here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/icml-2018-template/phsqtjnzytwg#.WnZmLWaZM6U))

How do I adjust the caption width in my working `\subfigure` syntax?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet compilable?

Comment: Why do you squeeze the subfigures into minipages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to have sub figures in line, you shouldn't have empty line between them (unless you wish to create a line break between the subfloasts). additionally consider:

- `\subfigure` is defined with deprecated package `subfigure`. It is superseded by the `subfig` package, with syntax `\subfloat[...][<title>]{....}` (see mwe below)
- with `\subfloat` the width of caption is equal to width of sub image.
- use of minipages is superfluous.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[subfigure a]{\label{fig:sa}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{clust3-actual12-outlier-removed}}
%
\subfloat[subfigure b]{\label{fig:sb}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.10]{clust11_long-actual75-outlier-removed}}
\caption{Figure}
\label{fig:s}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using the subcaption package?
My understanding was that subfig is also deprecated.

I'd use something like this:

```
\usepackage{subcaption, floatrow}
\begin{figure}[tp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{topleft.eps}
        \caption{top left caption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \enskip % Control spacing between left and right figure, can use \enskip, \quad, \qquad, \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{topright.eps}
        \caption{topright caption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\ % Force top and bottom figures onto a new line
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bottomleft.eps}
        \caption{bottomleft caption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \enskip % Control spacing between left and right figure, can use \enskip, \quad, \qquad, \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bottomright.eps}
        \caption{bottomright caption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Global figure caption}
    \label{global figure label}
\end{figure}
```

Otherwise you could try the floatrow package. I believe floatrow and subcaption play nicely with each other.

Comment: so far `subfig` is not deprecated, but `subcaption` is newer and more powerful :-). in op case, both gives the same result.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you for the clarification. :)